# How to pass data one page to another page using angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here I am Trying to Login with user credientials
if user is valid , I want to pass UserName,LastloginTime,Role values to another page using angular js

```
<form role="form" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MasterController">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                Username</label>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required ng-model="username" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required ng-model="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="remember">
                Remember my Password
            </label>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="GetData()" class="btn btn-danger" />
        <%--<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="GetData()">Submit</button>--%>
        <span ng-bind="Message"></span>
    </form>
```

js file here

```
   $scope.GetData = function () {
        debugger;
        var data = { UserName: $scope.username, Password: $scope.password };
        $http.post("api/Test/CheckUsername", data)
       .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           if (data != "") {
               $scope.Employees = data;
               window.location.href = "EmployeeMaster";
               //$scope.Reporting = data;
           }
           else {
               alert("Invalid Credientials");
           }

       });
    }
```

I want to display values in a master page

```
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr ng-repeat="Emp in Employees">
                                <th>User </th>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td>{{Emp.username}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Designation </th>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td>{{Emp.RoleName}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Last Login </th>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td>{{Emp.LastLogin}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

How can i pass the values login page to Home page?

Comment: can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: You can use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` as per your requirment. Refer [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) or `ngStorage`

Comment: What kind of navigation mechanism are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating a *service* to store your global data:

```
myApp.factory('DataService', function() {
    var user = {
        name: '',
        role: ''
        // and so on
    };

    return {
        user: user
    };
});
```

Just inject this to all your controllers and set and retrieve the data you need:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, DataService) {
    // make your DataService available in your scope
    $scope.DataService = DataService;
});
```

This lets you bind *models* globally to the `DataService`.

Comment: you suggest _service_ but create _factory_ :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out angular-storage A Storage done right for AngularJS. It is great for storing user info/tokens/ any object.

Key Features

Uses localStorage or sessionStorage by default but if it's not available, it uses ngCookies.
Lets you save JS Objects
If you save a Number, you get a Number, not a String
Uses a caching system so that if you already have a value, it won't get it from the store again.

https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of ways of to achieve this

1) Use $rootscope like you use $scope like

```
$rootscope.userName = ""
```

Inject the $rootscope dependency in the controller where you want to show it and create an object name Employee and fill it with $rootscope.

2) use constant like

```
module.constant("userData", data);
```

Inject the userData dependency in the controller where you want to show it and create an object name Employee and fill it with userData.

3) You can use service/factory and save the data in localstorage/sessionstorage

Answer (score 0):

to transfer data between pages, you can use stateParams:
in the routes file:

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('employeeMasterState', {
    url: '/employeeMasterUrl/:employeeData',
    templateUrl: 'info/employeeMaster.tpl.html',
    controller: 'employeeMasterCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'employeeMasterCtrlAs'
  });
```

js:

```
$scope.GetData = function () {
    debugger;
    var data = { UserName: $scope.username, Password: $scope.password };
    $http.post("api/Test/CheckUsername", data)
   .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       if (data != "") {
           this.state.go('employeeMasterState',{employeeData:data}); 

       }
       else {
           alert("Invalid Credientials");
       }

   });
}
```

in the next page js:

```
constructor($scope, $statePArams){
  $scope.empData = $stateParams.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service or a factory to share data between webpages. [Here is the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)